# Replacing the values in one column of Table1 with the values of Column from another Table2 in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables namely dup_table that comprises of:-

ROOM_NU   FLOOR     F_ID1

IS203    1       1234  
 IS221    1       1236  
 IS110    0       1239  
 IS112    0       1248  
 IS312    2       1252  
 IS317    2       1258   
 IS113    0       1263

We also have a table temp that comprises of :-

F_ID2

1267  
 1268  
 1275  
 1290  
 1298

ROOM_NU is the primary key of dup_table, F_ID1 is the foreign key of dup_table. F_ID2 is the foreign key of temp table.
Now I need to substitute all the values of F_ID2 of table temp i.e the entire column and replace it with F_ID1 values from dup_table. The number of entries in F_ID2 is less than F_ID1 so the remaining values are to be taken as before.

Is it possible to do in MySql? If so what will be the procedure or the corresponding query?

Comment: Yes this is possible with mysql.  Can you post your code?

Comment: what is the result you are expecting?